# Wi-Fi networks not visible after security and firmware update

Tags: wireless, 20.04

I have recently done a security and firmware update. Since then, no network appears under Wi-Fi.

Below is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network:0               
 

       description: Wireless interface
       product: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 30
       serial: d8:3b:bf:b1:dd:b6
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-25-generic firmware=46.6b541b68.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:9143c000-9143ffff

  *-network:1

       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (6) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno2
       version: 30
       serial: 34:48:ed:2f:ed:82
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.11.0-25-generic firmware=0.5-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:128 memory:91400000-9141ffff

  *-network

       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: veth546fd3f
       serial: 2e:b2:ed:15:39:c5
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
```

I have tried upgrading to the latest packages, but nothing helped.

Output of `uname -a`

```
Linux Latitude-5400 5.11.0-25-generic #27~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 13 17:41:23 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

[image: no networks visible in wifi settings dialog]

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.